# iOS - Adding objects to NSMutableDictionary causing crash

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In the app I'm developing I'm reading in a JSON file. This file contains a list of players. Each player has a series of attributes.

I have created a Mutable Array and a Mutable Dictionary to store the data. I'm trying to store the dictionary into an array index. I'm trying to do so with the following code:

```
var data = JSON(json!)
let players = data["API"]["Data"]
var i = 0
for (index:String, player:JSON) in players {
    if let name = player["name"].string { 
        //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
        self.pdata.setObject(name, forKey: "name")
    }
    if let serial = player["serial_number"].string {
        self.pdata.setObject(serial, forKey: "name")
    }
    if let status = player["player_status"].string {
        self.pdata.setObject(status, forKey: "status")
    }
    if let resolution = player["resolution"].string {
        self.pdata.setObject(resolution, forKey: "resolution")
    }
    if let lastConnected = player["last_connected"].string {
        self.pdata.setObject(lastConnected, forKey: "last_connected")
    }
    if let diskFree = player["disk_free_percent"].string {
        self.pdata.setObject(diskFree, forKey: "disk_free")
    }
    if let memTotal = player["mem_total_phys"].string {
        self.pdata.setObject(memTotal, forKey: "mem_total")
    }
    if let memAvail = player["mem_avail_phys"].string {
        self.pdata.setObject(memAvail, forKey: "mem_avail")
    }

    if(self.pdata.count > 0) {
        self.playerList.insertObject(self.pdata, atIndex: i)
        self.pdata.removeAllObjects()
        i++
    }
}
```

Using this code I'm getting the following error, even though I'm checking the value before assigning it:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: I commented the code where the error is. Line 7 (including the comment). Thanks.

Comment: player["name"] did you have data for this field? you can use player["name"].stringValue in this case if player["name"] nil the property returnes empty string

Comment: Any player that is returned by the API will have a name as that's a required field in the system. I will give .stringValue a shot though.

Comment: What type of type is `player["name"]` that it has a "string" property?

Comment: I use SwiftyJSON to parse the initial json response. The Players variable holds the section of json responsible for the player list. Player is a JSON type (which is actually SwiftyJSON).

Comment: @matcartmill You know what... I suspect `self.pdata` = nil. Could you post the code where you instantiate `self.pdata`?

Comment: I declare at the start of the class as: var pdata:NSMutableDictionary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SwiftyJSON, which it looks like you are, then it does a good job of protecting against nil values.  It is very likely that

If you declare pdata as:

```
var pdata:NSMutableDictionary!
```

Then this is the problem.  You are not creating a dictionary, but an optional.  At some point you have to actually create the dictionary.  You could do it in the same place simply by:

```
var pdata = NSMutableDictionary()
```

instead.

Comment: Wow. As if I missed that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

comment this code an check " name" value  i think problem can be in this part of code   `if(self.pdata.count > 0) {
        self.playerList.insertObject(self.pdata, atIndex: i)
        self.pdata.removeAllObjects()
        i++
    }`